# C#. Посчитать результат математического выражения с большими числами

Tags: c#, biginteger, mod

Есть строка, в котором записано число, состоящее из **большого** количества цифр:

```
var strN = "2132534245345345354787698678768678678";
```

Как вот это большое число можно "обрезать по модулю `X`? Для примера пусть
       `Х = 10^7 + 7`.

Т.е. нужно реализовать примерно такую функцию:

```
public static int ModBigNumber(string bigNum, int basis)
{
    return bigNum % basis; // Это просто для понимания того, что нужно сделать.
}
```

Идей совсем никаких нет, поэтому я засомневался, возможно ли такое вообще. Буду благодарен за помощь.

**UPD.** Текущий вопрос отпал, я оптимизировал код так, что нужно делать только 1 mod. Но теперь проблема в другом. *Функция преобразования* (см. ниже) для длины строки = 99 999 выполняется приблизительно 3 секунды. А это много для моей задачи.

```
var n = BigInteger.Parse(strN); // Время выполнения = 3,2 сек.
```

Кроме `mod` мне нужно еще умножить это число на 8 (не спрашивайте почему).

**UPD2.** Выражение, которое нужно вычислить:

```
var res = (digits[0] + 8 * n / 2 + sum - 1) % module;
```

где

- `digits[0]` - последняя цифра числа (например, в числе `1234` `digits[0] = 4`) типа `int/uint`;
- `n` - число, состоящее из 100 000 цифр;
- `sum` - число типа `int/uint`;
- `module` - основание, число типа `int/uint`.

Comment: [BigInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: в конкретно int - никак. Только BigInteger.

Comment: BigInteger очень медленный, у меня strN.Length <= 10^10000  и этот mod делается в цикле 10000 раз. Жаль, что нельзя

Comment: Возможно, надо пересмотреть алгоритм задачи, чтобы не делать 10000 делений в цикле. Но нам неизвестно, что вы делаете и зачем.

Comment: [How to compute mod of a big number?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compute-mod-of-a-big-number/)

Comment: _BigInteger очень медленный_ - одна из причин его медленности - генерация большого количества мусора, в результате чего много работает сборщик мусора. Хорошо помогает включение серверного GC (если у вас десктопное приложение). Думаю, нагуглите легко, как это сделать. Уточню: это не ускорит одну операцию с BigInteger, но ускорит общую работу с большим количеством операций.

Comment: ..и все-таки наверное strN.Length <= 10000 ? ;)

Comment: @tum_ я уже оптимизировал свой код, теперь mod делается всего один раз, но это все равно не делает мою проблему решенной, поскольку когда я делаю `BigInteger n = BigInteger.Parse(strN);` то эта штука выполняется около 3-х секунд, а это долго для моей задачи.

Comment: Я с# не знаю. Что делает эта Parse? Но 3 сек. для такой длины (сто тыщ десятичных цифр, точно?) - вполне разумный результат. Если число после этого парсинга получает двоичное представление - умножить на 8 это сдвинуть на 3 бита влево.

Comment: Почитал про BigInteger. Такая ещё мысль - откуда берутся эти длинные числа? Нельзя ли, чтобы они изначально были в Hex? Тогда время парсинга упадет очень сильно.

Comment: По upd2: еще не хватает двух вещей: какова точность (/10  дает дробь, нет?), и какое время выполнения сейчас и какое хотим получить?

Comment: По поводу вопроса `n / 10` - дает только целую часть от деления. Какое время сейчас - 3.2 секунды. Требуется < 1 сек

Comment: @tum_ я уже нашел решение, скоро опубликую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сравнение 2 версий. `ModWithSplit` разбивает большое число на куски по 9 цифр, `ModSimple` работает по одной цифре. При любых значениях длины большого числа разбиение по 9 цифр работает быстрее в несколько раз. Использовалась библиотека `BenchmarkDotNet`:

```
public static class ModHelper
{
    public static int ModWithSplit(string num, int module)
    {
        int tenPow9 = 1000000000 % module;

        long carry = 0;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < num.Length)
        {
            int partLen = Math.Min(9, num.Length - index);
            int tenPow;
            if (partLen == 9)
            {
                tenPow = tenPow9;
            }
            else
            {
                tenPow = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < partLen; j++)
                    tenPow *= 10;
            }

            int part = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < partLen; i++)
                part = part * 10 + num[index++] - '0';

            carry = (carry * tenPow + part) % module;
        }

        return (int)carry;
    }

    public static int ModSimple(String num, int a)
    {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
            res = (res * 10 + (int)num[i] - '0') % a;
        return res;
    }
}

public static class Mark
{
    [RPlotExporter, RankColumn]
    public class Runner
    {
        [Params(10, 20, 50, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)]
        public int N;
        private string strN;

        [IterationSetup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var rnd = new Random(1);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                sb.Append((char)('0' + rnd.Next(10)));

            strN = sb.ToString();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ModSimple()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                ModHelper.ModSimple(strN, 1234567);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ModWithSplit()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                ModHelper.ModWithSplit(strN, 1234567);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Runner>();
    }
}
```

Результаты:

```
|       Method |      N |          Mean |         Error |        StdDev |        Median | Rank |
|------------- |------- |--------------:|--------------:|--------------:|--------------:|-----:|
|    ModSimple |     10 |      4.478 us |     0.0904 us |     0.1267 us |      4.419 us |    2 |
| ModWithSplit |     10 |      2.979 us |     0.1176 us |     0.3098 us |      3.074 us |    1 |
|    ModSimple |     20 |     27.398 us |     4.2124 us |    12.4203 us |     37.638 us |    5 |
| ModWithSplit |     20 |      5.803 us |     0.1179 us |     0.1613 us |      5.667 us |    3 |
|    ModSimple |     50 |     69.022 us |    11.4606 us |    33.7919 us |     42.744 us |    6 |
| ModWithSplit |     50 |     11.671 us |     0.0000 us |     0.0000 us |     11.671 us |    4 |
|    ModSimple |    100 |     87.710 us |     0.1693 us |     0.1501 us |     87.618 us |    6 |
| ModWithSplit |    100 |     22.975 us |     0.1796 us |     0.1592 us |     22.861 us |    5 |
|    ModSimple |   1000 |    907.738 us |     0.3642 us |     0.3228 us |    907.623 us |    8 |
| ModWithSplit |   1000 |    209.736 us |     0.6659 us |     0.5199 us |    209.576 us |    7 |
|    ModSimple |  10000 |  9,277.088 us |   390.9399 us |   535.1229 us |  9,217.546 us |   10 |
| ModWithSplit |  10000 |  2,111.699 us |    45.0928 us |    42.1798 us |  2,103.780 us |    9 |
|    ModSimple | 100000 | 80,890.580 us | 3,242.7448 us | 9,510.4091 us | 79,399.141 us |   12 |
| ModWithSplit | 100000 | 19,957.108 us |   474.0542 us | 1,375.3173 us | 20,860.784 us |   11 |
```

Comment: зачем столько сложностей, я же кинул в коммент ссылку на код - там 3 строчки всего

Comment: @tym32167 там неоптимизировано, а автору нужна скорость. Хотя я не мерял скорость, возможно алокации новых стрингов в моем случае всё замедлят

Comment: аллокация, цикл, `int.Parse` - это всё вместе вашу оптимизацию съест

Comment: @tym32167 небольшая поправочка и мой метод работает быстрее в несколько раз :)

Comment: Ну конечно, если убрать всё, что его тормозит :)

Comment: @tym32167 но основная идея не менялась :)

Comment: так я никогда и не спорил с вами, просто думаю, что автору будет проще 3 строки понять, чем ваше решение. Но само по себе решение норм

Comment: @Zergatul взгляните, пожалуйста. Я обновил вопрос

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я так и не понял, что вам нужно. Посчитать `strN * 8 mod b`?

Comment: @Zergatul обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Все просто. Спасибо пользователю [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167) за предоставленную [ссылку](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compute-mod-of-a-big-number/) вычисления остатка числа, представленного строкой.

Используем функцию, предварительно модифицировав ее для беззнаковых чисел:

```
private static ulong Mod(string num, ulong a)
{
    ulong res = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        res = (res * 10 + num[i] - '0') % a;

    return res;
}
```

И преобразуем искомое выражение вот в такое:

```
var result = ((ulong)digits[0] + 8 * Mod(strN, module) / 2 + sum - 1) % module;
```

Comment: Может я и туплю, но искомое и преобразованное дают разные результаты... Вы правильность-то как-то проверяете?

Comment: @tum_ вроде как работает. Можно проверить на конкретных примерах

Comment: Тогда вы в условии задачи о чем-то умолчали или я порядок операций неправильно понимаю.. Берем n='10', mod=3, (sum-1) игнорируем т.к. константа пусть нулём побудет. Исх. дает 8%3=2, преобр даёт 4%3=1.

Comment: @tum_ упс, я здесь совершил описку. Вместо деления на 2 должно быть деление на 10. исправил ответ. Спасибо, что заметили)

Comment: Да на здоровье :) но результаты всё равно не сходятся. Не поспешили ли вы победу праздновать...

Comment: @tum_ действительно. А если делить на 2, а не на 10, то все будет верно? Просто у меня в программе деление на 2.

Comment: Так вы проверьте. Я тут только в полглаза думаю, но есть подозрение, что решение может оказаться в принципе неверным. … Нас уже в чат направляют..

Comment: @turn_ z видимо, данное выражение может быть неверно только если n <= 2. Потому что при остальных вроде как правильно вычисляет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91168/discussion-between-tum-and-andrei-khotko).